# Laravel, update all relations when deleting a record

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, one-to-many

I have two models, `Position` and `User`. They have a `One to many` relation between them.

When I delete a position, I want all the related users to be detached from that position and attached to a different one (found by id).

I'm sure it's simple enough, but I've tried doing it in a `foreach` loop, without success:

```
public function postDelete($position)
{
    $positionMembers = $position->users()->get();

    foreach ($positionMembers as $member) {
        $member->position_id = '4';

        // fixed copy/paste var name error
        $member->save()
    }

    // Was the position deleted?
    if($position->delete()) {
        // Redirect to the position management page
        return Redirect::to('admin/positions')->with('success', Lang::get('admin/positions/messages.delete.success'));
    }

    // There was a problem deleting the position
    return Redirect::to('admin/positions')->with('error', Lang::get('admin/positions/messages.delete.error'));
}
```

I've also tried:

```
$member->position()->associate($this->position->find(4));
```

but it doesn't work either. The position_id field always remains unchanged. Is there a more recommended way?

Comment: After `associate` you need to call `save()` and in the foreach loop you call `save()` on `$user`. Copy paste mistake?

Comment: lukasgeiter yes, thank you for pointing that out. It was just a copy/paste error. But I've also just tried `associate()->save()` and that doesn't seem to work either, unfortunately: `$member->position()->associate($this->position->find(4))->save();`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off define **without success**, because it says nothing, and the code you're showing should work.

Anyway, I would suggest different approach, for using Eloquent `save` in a loop isn't the best way:

```
public function postDelete($position)
{
    DB::transaction(function () use ($position, &$deleted) {

       // run single query for update
       $position->users()->update(['position_id' => 4]);

       // run another query for delete
       $deleted = $position->delete();
    });

    // Was the position deleted?
    if($deleted) {
        // Redirect to the position management page
        return Redirect::to('admin/positions')->with('success', Lang::get('admin/positions/messages.delete.success'));
    }

    // There was a problem deleting the position
    return Redirect::to('admin/positions')->with('error', Lang::get('admin/positions/messages.delete.error'));
}
```

With this, you make sure `users` don't get updated if there's some error(exception thrown) when deleting `position` and you execute 2 queries, no matter how many `users` there are to update.

Comment: Jarek, this worked, thanks. I just modified it a bit. I moved this line: `$this->users()->update(['position_id' => 4]);` to my `Position` model's `delete()` method. I think it's cleaner that way.

Comment: Yeah, definitely use `Post` methods/events for this if you want it always to happen.